# React App localhost:3000 logo not spinning

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

first ever post from me. Here it goes.

I have installed Visual Studio Code and wanted to create my first React app. I read through the documentation, used Syntax:

npx create-react-app my-react-app

Also used npm start

I get the Compiled successfully! message in the terminal. The http:localhost3000 page opens in a new tab. The React logo is displayed. For what ever reason the React logo is a static image for me. I edited text in the page's P tags and they update in real time. The Live Server extension seems to work as well.

Just about every tutorial on video has that logo spinning. My concern is not having React or even Visual Studio Code setup correctly from the beginning. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling 3x now. I get the same static image.

Any thoughts, experiences, or even conspiracy theories? Does the React logo spin for you? or static like mine? Is there any way I can make it spin every time I create a new React App? Every time my code is not working (do to my code most likely) I keep thinking about the React Logo.

node version 14.16.0
npm 6.14.11

Comment: I just tried it right now: npx create-react-app test and then cd test, yarn start. Logo is spinning for me.

This line in CSS is what is causing the spinner:

media (prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference) {
  .App-logo {
    animation: App-logo-spin infinite 20s linear;
  }
}

@keyframes App-logo-spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

do you have that in your CSS ?

Comment: Hello @Kevin, why you are so concerned about the animated logo? It's just an animation file :/ Add it as [here](https://codepen.io/Marlysson/pen/EWjOpX)

Comment: @DannyHobo Correct I have that code in App.css by default. Thanks for pointing out which code is responsible for that action.

Comment: @Aristotle My concern is consistency as well as saving time. I just want to ensure my setup is parallel to others I see. It appears it is even though the expected outcome is not. Mentally I just want to focus on code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as I said in the comments, no need to be concerned about the animated logo. Just an SVG file.

You can create your own as well [Check here](https://codepen.io/Marlysson/pen/EWjOpX)

Also, I generated a new project, and my logo spins.

First, check if you have the logo.svg file and then check
your App.css file.

```css
@media (prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference) {
  .App-logo {
    animation: App-logo-spin infinite 20s linear;
  }
}

@keyframes App-logo-spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

Also, you need to have them imported on your App.js,
both .css and .svg

Comment: Thanks Aristotle. I experimented with your linked code which was helpful. Also thanks for showing the importance of importing said logo and and .css into App.js its good fundamentals which is what I'm striving for.

Comment: @KevinOrara that's great to hear. Always remember when you create a `.js` file and a `.css` file to import it or otherwise the style won't be applied. If you want to learn more, and start from somewhere check the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html)

Answer (score 13):

I also got the same static React logo and here is how I fixed it (on Windows VM)

Symptom:

When you try the tutorial on https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html,
an animation effect settings of Windows may prevent the React Logo from spinning,

try either (1) or (2)

(1) [How to fix and make the react logo spin -- by changing Windows system setting)

Go to Window's Advanced setting system setting -> Performance Options,
Check "Animate controls and elements inside windows"
(As soon as you check this setting and apply, you can see the react logo start spinning.)

(2) [remove the part that is affected in the code by the above setting] (fix from inside css code)

Remove line 10 " (prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference) " from src/App.css

for more details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-reduced-motion

Looks like method 2 always works no matter what animation settings you have on your system. But as a tutorial, you might want to avoid making changes to the original source code from the beginning.

Comment: I ran the run the command sysdm.cpl via Run Dialog in Windows to get to Performance Options. I noticed that my Animate controls and elements inside windows is already checked.  I've ran npx create-react-app 'my-react-app' many times already and each time my React logo never spins :). Oh well at least there's no negative impact for actual app development thus far. Your option 2 may be the way to go?

Answer (score 6):

Had the same problem and this worked:

In App.css, on line 10, delete the line containing " (prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference) " and the closing bracket 3 lines below it.

Answer (score 2):

Delete only part ": no-preference" from line 10. It should be "@media (prefers-reduced-motion)", then the logo is spinning (at least mine).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue on Windows 10. Found this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-reduced-motion

And used this line to get it working:
In Windows 10: Settings > Ease of Access > Display > Show animations in Windows

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while working with Windows 10. I thought the same thing. Actually, one of the comments helped me.

In my case, it was because of my Windows settings.

Search in the Control Panel for "Adjust the appearance and performance of Windows" > and activate "Animate controls and elements inside Windows".

Comment: The top answer for the question has mentioned the exact same solution. There's no need for this answer to be posted.